# Node cluster: Ensure request completes before disconnecting worker

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am running a cluster of workers with nodejs. There is a memory leak which, due to an old and unfamiliar codebase, I have decided to fix by periodically killing workers and replacing them with new ones rather than diagnosing. As such I'm essentially using

```
setTimeout(() => {worker.disconnect();}, INTERVAL);
```

when we spawn a worker.

However, I want to make sure that when a worker is killed, it completes any request it is currently processing prior to being disconnected, so that requests aren't dropped. From experimenting with the library, calling `worker.disconnect()` drops a currently-processing request, causing an "empty reply from server" error. I would rather not manually implement logic to detect if a server is currently processing a request (e.g. by maintaining a set of active requests or something), due to edge cases. Is there a "standard" way of telling a cluster worker to "wait until the current request completes, and then exit"?

Answer (score 0):

So I have discovered something which seems to work, as far as I can tell. The strategy is to not have the master shut the worker down but instead let the worker shut itself down, after it has `close`d its server. The master sends it a message which the worker responds to. Something like (pseudocode)

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var worker = cluster.fork();

  // in 10 seconds, tell the worker to shutdown
  setTimeout(() => {worker.send('shutdown');}, 10000);
} else {
  var server = createServer(); // whatever server setup
  server.listen(PORT);

  process.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg === 'shutdown') {
      // disconnect from the cluster after the server closes
      server.close(() => {
        cluster.worker.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }
}
```